# Difference between $watch expressions in directive link vs controller function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've seen this done both ways; What is the difference between creating a scope.$watch in a directive controller vs the linking function?

Comment: There is no difference between the two as far as $watch is concerned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference as far as I can tell.  The scope passed in the linking is: "Scope - The scope to be used by the directive for registering watches."

So if you don't explicitly declare a controller or scope for the directive you still have a scope (taken from the context in which the directive is being compiled) to add watches to in the link function returned by the compile.

Answer (score 3):

There is *no* real difference between the two. At the matter of fact, the *$watch* expression will be accessible from both the controller and the directive regardless to where it was initially defined, as they both share the same $scope. That being said, a $watch in defined in the directive has a completely different purpose than a one defined in the controller.